# .NET Core 3.1 Not available in as Target Framework in VS2019 v16.6

Tags: visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I have downloaded and installed VS2019 Community v16.6.0
I have downloaded and installed .NET Core 3.1 (v3.1.4) with SDK version v3.1.300

.NET Core 3.1 is not available as an option for a target framework in Visual Studio. Am I missing something here?

I've followed several suggestions in other similar questions of enabling preview SDKs (which shouldn't apply, because 3.1 is not in preview) with no success.

Images Attached
[image: VS About SS]
[image: Core SDK Install SS]
[image: MS Recommended IDE/SDK combo SS]
[image: Avail Target Framework SS]

Comment: Check this thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/888468/net-core-31-is-not-showing.html
You may require to either remove the global.json file or update it use .NET Core 3.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v16.6.1 of VS2019 just dropped today. Fixed the issue.